# Convert Bson to Json in python

Tags: python, json, bson

I have a situation where I can only read BSON file as bytes (it is Apache Beam bytes coder). So I get BSON file content as bytes. Now I try to convert it to JSON. My code is:

```
from bson import json_util
import apache_beam as beam

class ParseBsontoJson(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        print(type(element))
        # data = bson.BSON.decode(bson.BSON(element))
        data = element.decode('utf-8')
        # data = bson.decode_all(element)
        # data2 = json_util.dumps(data)
        # print(type(data))
        return [data]

p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

# This gives me Pcollection of bytes (elements)
test = (p | 'test_r' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input + '/' + 'test.bson', coder=coders.BytesCoder()
| 'test_parse' >> beam.ParDo(ParseBsontoJson())) - here I have problem

data = element.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")
data2 = json_util.dumps(data)
print(data2)
```

Where `element` is a line in BSON file.

What I get is:

```
{
    "$binary": "w5MBAAAHX2lkAF5cw5/Dvj3Cu3FsIcKMOsO+Am5hbWUABgAAAHNjZW5lAAdhY2NvdW50SWQAXlzDn8OKw6B1OEp4TcKmXQdkYXRhQ2VudGVyAF5cw5/DizpiwrIWY8KLw5EIB3RzaGlydFNpemUAXlzDn8OLPcK7cWwhwow6Sgdvc0ltYWdlAF5cw5/Diz3Cu3FsIcKMOksHcHJvdmlzaW9uZWRCeVdvcmtPcmRlcgBeXMOfw5Q9wrtxbCHCjDpcB3BoeXNpY2FsU2VydmVyTm9kZQBeXMOfw5U9wrtxbCHCjDpmBGJvbmRzAHoAAAADMAByAAAAEGluZGV4AAAAAAAEbmljcwAoAAAAAzAAIAAAAAJtYWMAEgAAADhjOmZkOjFiOjAwOjlmOjk5AAAAB25ldHdvcmsAXlzDn8OmOmLCshZjwovDkTwCaXB2NEFkZHJlc3MADgAAADM4LjEzMy4xNjQuNjAAAAAEbHVucwAUAAAABzAAXlzDn8O+PcK7cWwhwow6w70AAnN0YXR1cwAOAAAAZGVwcm92aXNpb25lZAAJX3VwZGF0ZWQAMMO4w4rCmnABAAAJX2NyZWF0ZWQAMMO4w4rCmnABAAACX2V0YWcAKQAAAGMxN2QyZGNjOGU2ZGQ3ZGQ1NGI1ZGQzMjVlYjkzMDcyZTE2NWVmZjEAAMK5AgAAB19pZABeXMOgCTpiwrIWY8KLw5HCsQJuYW1lAAUAAABhd2F5AAdhY2NvdW50SWQAXlzDn8OKOmLCshZjwovDkQMHZGF0YUNlbnRlcgBeXMOfw4s6YsKyFmPCi8ORCQd0c2hpcnRTaXplAF5cw5/DjDpiwrIWY8KLw5E=",
    "$type": "00"
}
```

I tried another recommendations like for example from similar StackOverflow responses:

```
bson.decode_all(element)
```

or

```
# This give an exception: InvalidBSONbad eoo
data = bson.BSON.decode(bson.BSON(element))
```

But it doesn't convert it to JSON view.

```
element.decode('latin-1')
```

gives

```
"b²cÓ:nameimpactaccountId^\à=»ql!<RdataCenter^\à=»ql!<UtshirtSize^\à:b²cÒÞosImage^\à:b²cÒßprovisionedByWorkOrder^\à:b²cÒäphysicalServerNode^\à=»ql!<]bonds|0tindexnics(0 mac5d:b1:d1:82:d5:99network^"
```

Could you help me? I can't find in the internet how I can do this. All my tries receive exceptions.

I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: can you show how you get `element`?

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Edited to question. Python 3.7.

Comment: I am using apache beam ReadFromTExt with Bytes decoder

Comment: Isn't element an ordinary `dict` (or dict-like object)? What is `type(element)`?

Comment: type(element) returns <class 'bytes'>

Comment: Did you try `bson.loads(element)` without any encoding/decoding?

Comment: Yes. UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8 [while running 'test_parse']' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: What exactly is this: `"$binary": "w5MBAAAHX2lkAF...`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208925/discussion-between-tupteq-and-ovod).